How to download specific headless chrome version using google apis
I'm using this link:
https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/chromium-browser-snapshots/o/Linux_x64%2F1192597%2Fchrome-linux.zip?generation=1693941360490354&alt=media
To download this version: HeadlessChrome/118.0.5993.0 into docker environment.
I need to download this version: HeadlessChrome/103.0.5058.0 but I can't find the correct link for it.
I tried using https://chromiumdash.appspot.com/ to find the version and the respective commit but nothing for the link.
Seems like the only dynamic param is 982924 and I can't find it for the needed version.
Did someone encounter this issue before? Any suggestions on how to solve this?

It is not an easy task since there might be no Chromium build for a specific Chrome version. Note that the builds you try to access are Chromium builds and not Chrome builds. In general, you would have to go to https://chromiumdash.appspot.com/branches, find the branch position for the milestone version you need (for M103, it is 1002911) and then go to https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Linux_x64/ and try to find the closest branch position if there is no exact match.
Builds for more recent milestones should be available via Chrome for Testing and it is recommended to use those https://developer.chrome.com/blog/chrome-for-testing/
P.S. the link you provided in your post does not work for me

Thanks i'll try what you suggested, and also I updated my post with the correct link :)
